# How to redirect the output of an interactive program to a file?

Tags: java

I have an interactive java program which takes input from user...now i need to redirect whatever output that has been printed on the screen to a file? Is is possible.

From the java docs I got the method "System.setOut(PrintStream ps);" but i am not getting as to how to use this method?

E.g. I have  a program as:

```
public class A{
  int i;
   void func()
   {
      System.out.println("Enter a value:");
      Scanner in1=new Scanner(System.in);
      i= in1.nextInt();
      System.out.println("i="+i);
   }
 }
```

Now i want to redirect the output given below to a file:

```
 Enter a value:
 1
 i=1
```

Comment: if you don't need to do it programmatically, you can redirect the output from the command line (while interacting, you won't see the output anyway, if you want to, you can use `tee` or similar)

Comment: @Jannat Arora, are you aware that if you redirect the standard output to a file then the user won't have a clue what he is supposed to do (e.g. `Enter a value:`)? Also, redirecting the input was not even contemplated in your initial question

Comment: @Alexander Sorry for the initial question...but this is my actual question...can someone pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"))));
```

To write something to a file there a number of ways, you can take a look at [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) tutorial.

In your case, if you would like to print exactly what is on the screen in a file too, even the user input, you can do something like:

```
void func(){                                                                                             
  try {                                                                                                  
    PrintStream out=new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")));       
    System.out.println("Enter a value:");                                                                
    out.println("Enter a value:");                                                                       
    Scanner in1=new Scanner(System.in);                                                                  
    int i= in1.nextInt();                                                                                
    out.println(i);                                                                                      
    System.out.println("i="+i);                                                                          
    out.println("i="+i);                                                                                 
    out.close();                                                                                         
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                                                                    
    System.err.println("An error has occurred "+e.getMessage());                                         
    e.printStackTrace();                                                                                 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dan...can u pls write an example code...to illustrate how it works...please

Comment: @dan thanks a lot...i have another doubt...can we redirect the output to a string instead of the file "output.txt"

Comment: @JannatArora Sure you can, just replace the `PrintStream out=...` with  `ByteArrayOutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutputStream();` and after everything is written you will get your string with: `String result= new String( out.toByteArray());`

Comment: @dan Thanks again dan...but if i want to use System.setout()..the function u gave..now i want to return to normal output console..how should i do so

Comment: @JannatArora `ByteArrayOutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutputStream(); System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));` and after everything is written, using `System.out.println();`, you will use the same call: `String result= new String( out.toByteArray());` to retrieve your string content.

Answer (score 0):

classes in java.io package are designed for that. i recommend you to have a look at [java.io package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html).

**After you edit.**

```
   File file = new File("newFile.txt");
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    pw.println("your input to the file");
    pw.flush();

     pw.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  // all to the console    
        System.out.println("This goes to the console");
        PrintStream console = System.out; // save the console out for later.
  // now to the file    
        File file = new File("out.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println("This goes to the file out.txt");

  // and back to normal
        System.setOut(console);
        System.out.println("This goes back to the console");
```